# Force Rerendering a template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, video.js

I have a template that plays a video at `http://meteor.local/videoPlayer/:_id`

This works fine for me, But when I try to click another video the template doesn't rerender. The problem there is I'm using the onRendered function to instantiate a video.js instance.

The two videos are using the same template but of course the underlying data changes.

Is there a method somewhere that will allow me to rerender a template?

Comment: Can't you try setting up a variable in your template and in your onRendered function pass in that variable so it changes every time the page reloads?

Comment: @Optymystyc What's the context of the template and does it change when you click on a new video? (e.g. what is `this.data` inside of `onRendered`)

Comment: This might be helpful for `video.js` - https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md#alternative-setup-for-dynamically-loaded-html

Comment: @Blkc, I could try to set a Session variable and take advantage of it's reactivity but I am also using Iron-router and setting things within the data context.